# How to display html content in particular frame only?

Tags: html, css, iframe, summernote

I am using summer-note editor in Back-end and storing that HTML content in database and i have loaded that HTML content between `<div></div>` tags.

when that page load in the front site all the uploaded CSS apply in whole page like

I have wrote this code in editor

```
h5 {
  text-align; right;
}
```

and this will applied into the another `<h5>` tag of that page.

So, What is the solution for that i just want to apply that editor css in particular div only? Please guide me on this.

I just want to display that HTML in frame only.

Answer (score 5):

You need to assign that DIV a class or ID, and then, using the CSS selectors, you can only style the section you desire, and then you can access the class using `.` and ID by declaring `#`
see the below:

```css
.class-selector{
    text-align:center;
    color:red;
}

#id-selector{
    text-align:center;
    color:blue;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="class-selector"> Hello World! (Class Selector)</h1>
<h1 id="id-selector"> Hello World! (Id Selector)</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
h5 .class_Name {
  text-align; right;
}
```

And give that class to the div you want .
If you are having further doubt, add in comment.
Thank you

Comment: this text-align: right is added from the back-end summer-note editor and html data are stored in the database and this editors h5 tag css was applied in all the h5 tag

Comment: is it possible to create className in html stored in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Give that `div` a class name and target the h5 within that class. For eg.

```
<style>
.text h5 {
    text-align: right;
}
</style>

<div class="text">
    <h5>Some text</h5>
</div>
```

Now, by doing this that h5 style will only be applied the specific one you want to.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style only one  tag then you should give id to that  tag and if you want to style multiple  tags but not all then you should give class to those .

HTML:-

`<h5 id="idOfh5"> Hello H5 </h5>`

CSS:-
`h5#idOfh5{text-align: right;}`

And

HTML:-

`<h5 class="classOfh5"> Hello H5 </h5>`

CSS:-
`h5.classOfh5{text-align: right;}`